# Backbone fetch() success callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, callback

In my app, there are different user accounts. What I'm trying to do is, show a `loader.gif` till the time `.fetch()` is fetching the content from resource url + rendering the views and hide the `loader` when fetching is done.

Now, when a user logs in, his list of TODO items 
is fetched by `Todos.fetch` and on success callback, `loader.gif` fades out.

```
$("#app").hide();
$(".loader").show();
Todos.fetch({
    success: function(){
            $("#app").show();
            $(".loader").hide();
        }
});
```

This works fine for all user except those which have no `Todo` items. For these users, success callback is not triggered and `loader.gif` stays. Is there any other way to hide the `loader.gif`?

---

It seems to me that `success` function is called only when even a single model is added to the collection. If there is nothing to add to the collection, `success` isn't called.

Comment: Some code to demonstrate your problem would help.

Comment: Added the code. Although I don't think there's any issue with the code because when there is `Todo` items to load i.e when there is something to add to `Todos` collection, the function is called. Though, when there is nothing to be added to the `Todos` collection, the function is not called.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

BackboneJS fetch delegates to sync. sync returns a jqXHR object for your own use.

You could just:

```
Todos.fetch({
    success: function(){
            $("#app").show();
            $(".loader").hide();
        }
}).always(function() { $(".loader").hide() });
```

You can read more about it in [this blog post](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/backbone-js-models-save-always-callback/).

Apart from that, make sure that your server returns a valid json when the collection is empty. If the response is not a valid json you will get a failure.

Comment: Great find :) Thanks a ton and am using Rails which takes care of most of the things.

Comment: Nice find! But keep in mind it does not provide the (model, response, options) arguments that you would expect in the success-callback. So you have to find another way to access the model again, if that's what you were doing in your success-callback.